# Form overlapping another form?

Tags: html, css, web

I have two separate forms. However, the second form is overlapping the first, instead of being beneath. I can confirm it is a CSS issue, however I cannot work out what it is - it has had me puzzled for ages, and now I'm finally giving up.

Here is the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNPgbW

```
.comments-section .comment-form {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: .company-profile height. :)

Comment: Rather than using this layout, take a look at the <label> tag.  It's a much more concise way to layout this form, and it's more symantically correct as well.

Comment: Feel like an idiot. Thanks, been staring at this for so long. Thanks for the heads up about <label> tag, trying to get into the routine for good programming practices.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your .company-profile class is being restricted to 200px tall. Your first form doesn't fit into that height and overflows that container but it won't push down the next form because you told it to only be 200px tall. Remove that height and it will fix the issue.